# problems in appending elements to associative array in bash

Tags: bash

I have a block of codes like this in bash:

```
tencent=()
while read line
  do
  index=$(echo $line | awk '{printf "%s", $1}')
  value=$(echo $line | awk '{printf "%s", $2}')
  sindex="S_"$index
  tencent[$sindex]=$value
done < $TENCENT_BILLS_MERGED
```

But I get just only one element in this array afterwards, can anyone help me fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare associative array rather than indexed array since you use string/key as index.

> Indexed arrays are referenced using integers (including arithmetic
>   expressions) and are zero-based; associative arrays are referenced
>   using arbitrary strings.
>
> Associative arrays are created using declare -A name.

Therefore;

```
tencent=()
```

should be

```
declare -A tencent
```

Answer (score 1):

As you declare your variable `tencent`, it is a classic array with numeric index.

You should declare it as an [associative array](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays) to make it work, like so:

```
declare -A tencent
```